# how to retrieve Index value of an object ID Value, form an array with multply objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Please How can i retrieve the index of these array, mostly when i loop through it by

```
var objRecord = {"ID":1,"Name":"Precious","PhoneNo":08051170615,"Address":"London"}
var arrData = [objRecord];

arrData.push({ "ID": 2, "Name": "locas", "PhoneNo": 08051109615, "Address": "gameondon"})
```

my aim is to get the index of the second element with ID 2

using these function

```
function  GetElementIndex(id) {

        //code  

}
```

Comment: `var index = arrData.push(...) - 1` or `var index = arrData.findIndex(a => a.ID === 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function GetElementIndex(id) {
    var returnIndex = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
        if (arrData[i].ID == id) {
            returnIndex = i
            break;
        }
    }
    return returnIndex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, yours worked

Comment: I like your Method

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetElementIndex(id, arr){
   let index = 0
   arr.forEach((item, i) => {
     if(item.ID === id){
       return index += i
     }
   })
  return index
}
```

that should do the trick

Comment: That returns a list of objects, not the index.

Comment: @str like this work perfectly

Comment: No please do not do that, it is terrible.

Comment: @str prefer that way mister ?

Comment: Better but still bad. There is no need to increment the `index` variable as `forEach` already provides it. But anyway, you should use `findIndex`  instead. It is meant for exactly that use case and has the better performance as it returns as early as possible.

Comment: @str ye should have looked at mdn, didn't knew there was this one, but pointing that makes all response irrelevant when there is one method that do it (or not irrelevant but not the best approach)

Comment: Yes. That is why we are encouraged to close questions as duplicate. Older questions tend to have better and more thorough answers on many topics.

Comment: @str i got it, thanks for pointing that ^^ makes perfect sense !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` of Array.prototype.

```js
var objRecord = {"ID":1,"Name":"Precious","PhoneNo":08051170615,"Address":"London"}
var arrData = [objRecord];

arrData.push({ "ID": 2, "Name": "locas", "PhoneNo": 08051109615, "Address": "gameondon"})

function  GetElementIndex(id) {
    var index;
    arrData.forEach(function(e,i){
      if(e.ID===id && !index)
        index=i;
    });
    return index;
}

console.log(GetElementIndex(2));
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple code that will return the index of the item you want :

```js
var objRecord = {"ID":1,"Name":"Precious","PhoneNo":08051170615,"Address":"London"}
var arrData = [objRecord];

arrData.push({ "ID": 2, "Name": "locas", "PhoneNo": 08051109615, "Address": "gameondon"}) 

var found = arrData.find(e => {
  return e.ID == 2;
})

console.log(arrData.indexOf(found))
```

Here the idea is to use the array.prototype.find() method to get the element corresponding to your ID, then using indexOf to find the index in the array (here it is 1 because first index starts at 0).

Comment: Thank you so much, please where can i learn how to use these array methods with examples

Comment: @donpreciousiyeritufu [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is the best resource for things like this. You should start by reading about [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) which would have been the better answer to your question in the first place.

Comment: I had Issues with found, i cant convert your code to a function

Comment: Thanks for the info